# Xcode doesn't see OpenMP

Tags: xcode, macos, openmp, macos-big-sur

I've install OpenMP via homebrew:

> brew install libomp

But Xcode doesn't see file in my c-project:

> 'omp.h' file not found

Reinstallation of omp doesn't fix it.

How to fix this problem?

OS: Big Sur (Intel)

Answer (score 0):

> I've install OpenMP via homebrew:

Not exactly. You've installed an Open MP runtime library, but that is no use with a compiler that supports OpenMP, and Apple's compilers do not.

Since you are using `homebrew` already you can clearly use it to install a compiler which does support OpenMP. Both GCC and LLVM support OpenMP and are available in homebrew, which you choose is up to you.